# Why rsync creates an unnamed folder on destination?

Tags: linux, rsync

I use the following script to put folders with the prefix `old_` and their contents on an usb hard disk.
For some reason, `rsync` creates a nameless folder into which the data is copied.

```
rsync -vrhm --stats --progress --include='**/' --include='**/old_*/**'  --exclude='@Recycle' --exclude='*' /share/Projekte/ /share/02-18-Harburg/
```

How can i change this?
Also, I would like to know if it is possible for `rsync` to delete these files that have been previously transfered from source?

EDIT:

This is what i get when try to tab the directory:

```
$ cd 02-18-Harburg/^M/2017/
```

The folder has following name:

```
$ ls -lisah
total 0
27 0 drwxr-xr-x 1 admin administrators 0 2018-05-18 13:32 ?/
```

[image]

Comment: It can't be nameless. What's it called?

Comment: @roaima Look at this. Isn't it unnamed?

Comment: How does the relevant source tree look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^M` in `02-18-Harburg/^M/2017/` is the carriage return character. Your script has a Windows-style CRLF line ending, so the path `rsync` sees, is `/share/02-18-Harburg/<CR>`. It dutifully creates a path of that name.

(The `^M` notation usually refers to hitting <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>. A more common notation for the carriage return as a character is `\r`.)

Fix the line ending in the script with something like `dos2unix`, or `sed -i 's/\r//' script` (assuming GNU sed).

`ls` doesn't like to output special characters in filenames to the terminal, so it prints a `?` instead. Which is actually a good thing here, since you couldn't see the real CR on the terminal anyway. Use `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape` to have it print the filenames in a less ambiguous format.